# send automatic email to users

Tags: java, mysql, sendmail

I want to send an automatic email once in the month (in day 28). locally the method is working and the email is sent, but when I deployed the application on the server the method of sending the emails does not work, and therefore the email does not send to users.
I d'ont know what the problem ??

note:  the prod database on the cloud (putty).
the application works on prod and it does not show any problem, but the method of sending emails does not work because it doesn't send emails

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
            SpringApplication.run(SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.class, args);
    
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/...","name database","password");
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
            int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
            
            if(day == 28) {
            Statement ccf = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet ddj = ccf.executeQuery("SELECT gestion_cra.employe.email FROM gestion_cra.employe");
                  while(ddj.next()) {
                    String mel = ddj.getString("email");
                    JavaMailUtil.senMail(mel);  
                 }
                  
           }
```

Method sendMail :

```
public static void senMail(String recepiant) throws MessagingException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "send.one.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    String MyAccountEmail = "mail";
    String Password ="password";
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(MyAccountEmail, Password);
        }
    });
            
    Message message = prepareMessage(session, MyAccountEmail, recepiant);
    
    Transport.send(message);
        
}
```

application.properties:

```
jwt.secret=....//
jwt.get.token.uri=/login

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/...
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.datasource.username = //name of database
spring.datasource.password = //password
server.address=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Without looking into the error you are getting in prod I dont think we can help you

Comment: You have to debug your code to see where it fails exactly. Sending bulk emails may actually fail not because of the program but because of spam prevention measures or misconfiguration. So without making sure whether the program itself works you wouldn't be able to tell.